# Using a saved scikit learn model to see the classes in the model

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a saved trained sci-kit learn model as a joblib dump (.sav file). The training dataframe is unavailable. All I have is the test dataframe.

Here is the code to the following problem :

```
# Read Dataset
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")

# Feature Selection
x_df = df[feature_list]
y_df = df[target_list]

# Split Dataframe for Train and Test
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_df, y_df, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

# SVM Classifier
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.externals import joblib

model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear',random_state=0)
model.fit(x_train,y_train.values.ravel())
file_name = 'model.sav'
joblib.dump(model, file_name)
```

Now, what I am trying to do here is to get the names of all the classes present in the training dataframe.

Is it possible to get this information from just the sav file? If yes, how?
Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your answer telling which model you have used, etc.

Comment: what is the output of `type(joblib.load(filename))`?

Comment: An answer will depend on the code, used for building that model. Was there any preprocessing step (like binarizing) applied to labels (classes)? What exactly was dumped (saved) by `joblib`? Please post a corresponding code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, load the model using joblib

```
model = joblib.load("model.sav")
```

Then, you can get the class names using the following command

```
model.classes_
```